# Portmonteau's Theorem works if we demand only compactness, if $X_n$ are dense

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

When introducing Portmanteau's Theorem my Probability Theory course gave the following exercise for the reader.

Assume $X, X_n$ are real random variables such that $(X_n)_n$ is tight. Further, assume
$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(X_n\in K)\le P(X\in K)\tag{1}$$
holds for all compact of $K\subset\mathbb R$. Show that $X_n\rightarrow X$ in distribution. Why can't we drop the tightness assumption?

The first statement would follow directly from the assumption by Portmanteau, if we replace "for all compact" with "for all closed". Is there some way to get from compact sets to closed sets using tightness?

EDIT an answer to the second question is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275297/portmanteau-theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon >0$. Since $(X_n)_n$ is tight, there exists $a>0$ such that
$$\sup_n\mathbb{P}(|X_n|>a) < \varepsilon.$$
Now let $F \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a closed subset. We have
$$\mathbb{P}(X_n \in F) \leq \mathbb{P}(X_n \in F\cap [-a,a])+\mathbb{P}(|X_n| >a )\leq \mathbb{P}(X_n \in F\cap [-a,a])+\varepsilon.$$
Since $F\cap [-a,a]$ is compact, we get
$$\limsup_n \mathbb{P}(X_n \in F)\leq \mathbb{P}(X\in F\cap [-a,a]) + \varepsilon \leq \mathbb{P}(X\in F) + \varepsilon.$$
This holds for every $\varepsilon >0$, thus letting $\varepsilon \to 0$ we deduce that for every closed subset $F \subset \mathbb{R}$
$$\limsup_n \mathbb{P}(X_n \in F)\leq \mathbb{P}(X\in F).$$
It follows from the Portmanteau theorem that $X_n$ converges to $X$ in distribution.